# Sort by multiple values and make a leaderboard mongodb mongoose discord.js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

Is there an ideal way to make a leaderboard for multiple values? For example Id want to display the user who has the highest overall stats from the schema below. Using Mongodb mongoose discord.js

```
const statSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    userName: String,
    userId: String,
    HLTV: String,
    ADR: String,
    HS: String,
    W: String,
    L: String,
    T: String,
    win_percent: String
```

Comment: Well that depends on what counts as "overall" do you want us to count `L` or `userId` or not? please list how you *wish* you could rank them but don't know how.

Comment: Its rather difficult to think of a best way to rank the best players over all. I think it would be best to determine the best players overall with their win percentage, ADR and HLTV

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you can only rank somebody with a singular int. not using 2 if both ints are valued differently. So I suggest a "point" system that determines their ranking.

*Note: I don't know what `ADR` or `HLTV` stands for so imma come up new items*

So lets say we assign every `WIN` to 10 points, and every `LOSS` to -5 points.

someone with 1 win would have `10` points

someone with 1 win and a lost would have `5` points.

Meaning we can now judge between the two.

If we took something like `Hard_Games_Played` and gave the players `10` extra points.

Someone who has won more *hard games* would be ranked higher than someone with normal games won.